# Can we use "accounts for" to describe an absolute value rather than a proportion?

Tags: phrase-usage

A common usage of the phrase "account for" :

> 1 Healthcare system accounts for 32% of the total expenditure.

> 2 National government accounts for 32% of the total financial resources.

Can we also say:

> 3 Healthcare system accounts for $30 billion.

> 4 National government accounts for $10 billion of the total budget.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

But note, that 'Healthcare system' needs an article.